# Selecting unique values from the result set using MySQL stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor, unique

Selecting distinct values from the above result set i.e, thereby eliminating duplicate values and finally storing these values into a variable with a comma-separated list of values. Such that variable assigned with a comma-separated list of values must be given as an input to another SQL IN Operator

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `someDB`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AAA`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `AAA`(IN `feed_setting_user_id` BIGINT)
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
  DECLARE FoFID, FoFUsername, friendID, friendUsername TEXT;
  DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 

        SELECT `u`.`ID`, `u`.`username` FROM `users` `u`  
        WHERE `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `u1`.`ID` FROM users `u1` 
            WHERE `u1`.`ID` IN 
            (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM user_friends `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = feed_setting_user_id ) 
             OR `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf2`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf2` WHERE `uf2`.`status` = '2' AND `uf2`.`friendid` = feed_setting_user_id) 
             AND `u1`.`ID` != feed_setting_user_id);

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;

        OPEN friend_cursor;
        friend_loop: LOOP
            FETCH FROM friend_cursor INTO friendID, friendUsername;
            IF exit_loop THEN
                LEAVE friend_loop;
            END IF;
            -- SELECT  friendID, friendUsername;
            SELECT `u`.`ID`, `u`.`username` FROM `users` `u` WHERE `u`.`ID` NOT IN (feed_setting_user_id) AND `u`.`ID` 
                            IN (SELECT `u1`.`ID` FROM `users` `u1` 
                            WHERE `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = friendID AND `uf`.`friendid` != friendID) 
                            OR `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf2`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf2` WHERE `uf2`.`status` = '2' AND `uf2`.`friendid` = friendID AND `uf2`.`userid` != friendID) AND `u1`.`ID` != friendID ); 
        END LOOP friend_loop;
        CLOSE friend_cursor;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Actual Result:**

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | username  |
+----+-----------+
|  5 | SpiderMan |
|  8 | AntMan    |
|  9 | Bat       |
| 11 | SuperMan  |
| 12 | Arrow     |
| 13 | CAmerica  |
+----+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.53 sec)

+----+----------+
| ID | username |
+----+----------+
|  9 | Bat      |
| 10 | BatMan   |
| 13 | mustafa  |
+----+----------+
3 rows in set (0.61 sec)

+----+-----------+
| ID | username  |
+----+-----------+
|  5 | SpiderMan |
|  6 | Hulk      |
|  9 | Bat       |
| 10 | BatMan    |
+----+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.69 sec)

+----+----------+
| ID | username |
+----+----------+
|  8 | AntMan   |
|  9 | Bat      |
| 10 | BatMan   |
| 11 | SuperMan |
+----+----------+
4 rows in set (0.78 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.86 sec)
```

**Expected Result:**

```
5,6,8,9,11,12,10,13
```

We need to assign the above list of comma separated values into a variable.
So that we need to eliminate duplicates from the above list of values.

---

**Update:**

Tried to implement nested cursors

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `someDB`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AAA`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `AAA`(IN `feed_setting_user_id` BIGINT)
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
  DECLARE FoFID, FoFUsername, friendID, friendUsername TEXT;
  DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE exit_loop1 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 

        SELECT `u`.`ID`, `u`.`username` FROM `users` `u`  
        WHERE `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `u1`.`ID` FROM users `u1` 
            WHERE `u1`.`ID` IN 
            (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM user_friends `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = feed_setting_user_id ) 
             OR `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf2`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf2` WHERE `uf2`.`status` = '2' AND `uf2`.`friendid` = feed_setting_user_id) 
             AND `u1`.`ID` != feed_setting_user_id);

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;

        OPEN friend_cursor;
        friend_loop: LOOP
            FETCH FROM friend_cursor INTO friendID, friendUsername;
            IF exit_loop THEN
                LEAVE friend_loop;
            END IF;
--          SELECT  friendID, friendUsername;


            DECLARE friend_of_friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 

             SELECT `u`.`ID`, `u`.`username` FROM `users` `u` WHERE `u`.`ID` NOT IN (feed_setting_user_id) AND `u`.`ID` 
                            IN (SELECT `u1`.`ID` FROM `users` `u1` 
                            WHERE `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = friendID AND `uf`.`friendid` != friendID) 
                            OR `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf2`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf2` WHERE `uf2`.`status` = '2' AND `uf2`.`friendid` = friendID AND `uf2`.`userid` != friendID) AND `u1`.`ID` != friendID );
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop1 = TRUE;               

            OPEN friend_of_friend_cursor;
                friend_of_friend_loop: LOOP
                    FETCH FROM friend_of_friend_cursor INTO FoFID, FoFUsername;
                    IF exit_loop1 THEN
                        LEAVE friend_of_friend_loop;
                    END IF;

                SELECT  FoFID, FoFUsername;

                END LOOP friend_of_friend_loop;
            CLOSE friend_of_friend_cursor;

        END LOOP friend_loop;
        CLOSE friend_cursor;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Results:**

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE friend_of_friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 

             SELECT `u`.`ID`, `u`.`user' at line 29
```

Comment: For starters get rid of the cursor. If you post you source data then I am 99% sure someone will come up with a solution that does not require it. This looks way too procedural to me.

Comment: @TomC Are there any online stored procedures you may know to post the data or do you have any better idea for implementing such case?

Comment: @Nishanthॐ since you are expecting only the id's we can use to store the result in a temporary table.

Comment: Will you post it in answer for getting rid of duplicate values @James

Comment: Sure  will update

Comment: @Nishanthॐ This can easily be accomplished in a recursive CTE, assuming you are at a version of MySQL that supports CTEs. If you provide your sample data then it will be simple to create. No way this should need a cursor. I'd ask a new questionif you want this answered along with the lines of "how to replace this cursor with a CTE" and post the sample data.

Comment: @TomC it seems that OP is using Version 5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below sp

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `someDB`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AAA`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `AAA`(IN `feed_setting_user_id` BIGINT)
    modifies SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
DECLARE v_friendID, FoFID bigint; # use datatype which is used for u.ID used int based on ur result
DECLARE exit_loop, exit_loop1 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT `u`.`ID` FROM `users` `u`  
    WHERE `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `u1`.`ID` FROM users `u1` 
    WHERE `u1`.`ID` IN 
    (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM user_friends `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = feed_setting_user_id ) 
    OR `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf2`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf2` WHERE `uf2`.`status` = '2' AND `uf2`.`friendid` = feed_setting_user_id) 
    AND `u1`.`ID` != feed_setting_user_id);

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;

drop temporary table if exists unique_tbl; #precaution: when sp stops with error 
create temporary table unique_tbl (user_id bigint unique); #to avoid duplicate added unique

insert into unique_tbl values (feed_setting_user_id); # added input from sp

    OPEN friend_cursor;
    friend_loop: LOOP

        FETCH friend_cursor INTO v_friendID;

        IF exit_loop THEN
            LEAVE friend_loop;
        ELSE

            replace into unique_tbl values (v_friendID); # since we need all unique id's using replace if exists

            fof: begin

                DECLARE friend_of_friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 
                    SELECT `u`.`ID` FROM `users` `u` WHERE `u`.`ID` NOT IN (feed_setting_user_id) AND `u`.`ID` 
                    IN (SELECT `u1`.`ID` FROM `users` `u1` 
                    WHERE `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = v_friendID AND `uf`.`friendid` != v_friendID) 
                    OR `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf2`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf2` WHERE `uf2`.`status` = '2' AND `uf2`.`friendid` = v_friendID AND `uf2`.`userid` != v_friendID) 
                    AND `u1`.`ID` != v_friendID );

                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop1 = TRUE;

                OPEN friend_of_friend_cursor;
                friend_of_friend_loop: LOOP

                    FETCH friend_of_friend_cursor INTO FoFID;

                    IF exit_loop1 THEN
                        LEAVE friend_of_friend_loop;
                    END IF;

                    replace into unique_tbl values (FoFID);

                END LOOP friend_of_friend_loop;
                CLOSE friend_of_friend_cursor;
            end;
        end if;
    END LOOP friend_loop;
    CLOSE friend_cursor;

select group_concat(user_id) from unique_tbl; #this will show result in comma seperated 2,34,56,78

#cleanup
drop temporary table if exists unique_tbl;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I need to run one more query above the #cleanup as `SELECT u.ID FROM users u WHERE u.ID IN ((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) FROM unique_tbl),feed_setting_user_id);`  **Results:** `Error Code: 1050
Table 'unique_tbl' already exists`

Comment: Create another thread or where you have tried to insert the query.

Comment: you can't call feed_setting_user_id inside in, it throws error "Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row". What exactly you need?

Comment: As I need to include `feed_setting_user_id` into comma separated list of values in the final resulting values

Comment: ok Tested. Does this temporary table `unique_tbl ` get's affected with concurrent users or based on the `feed_setting_user_id` why can't we save all the `user_id`?

Comment: This is based on the input `feed_setting_user_id` it will get result from 1st cursor and parse the value into 2nd cursor if matches, then input & output of all unique ids will be shown as result.